# Storing configuration information for a solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, configuration

I have a bunch of console applications that trigger each other or are called by a scheduler, a website that serves as a front end to these, and a database which all of the applications have access to.

All of the applications have their own `app.config` / `web.config` files. However, there is some information (to do with server locations, error reporting controls and so on) that all these applications need to know about.

Where is the best place to store this configuration information? My first idea was to store it in the SQL server in a `Configuration` table, but this isn't that appealing.

where should I store configuration information that all projects/applications in a solution have access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store this in the same place as your shared `AssemblyInfo.cs` or your strong name key file (.snk)- that is assuming you share those files across your projects.

So your root folder of your solution would look like:

Project1Dir
Project2Dir
AssemblyInfo.cs
MySolution.sln
key.snk
shared.config

and you would use 'Add as Link' for each of your projects that require `shared.config`

Comment: That seems like a fairly good idea, but will it work well if information needs to be updated on a deployed system? For instance, my system has a list of email addresses to which errors/warning messages are sent. This is the sort of thing I might need to update after deployment.

Comment: The shared config would just be another file in each of your projects, just like the projects `app.config` - so the process would be the same as how you manage updates to other 'static' files in your project. How you manage config files in deployed solutions is another topic in itself (is that what you are asking?)

Comment: The different is, a projects `app.config` file is only in one place. If you need to change it, you can just find the file, then edit it. `shared.config` would be cloned for each of the projects, so to change it in a deployed solution, you'd have to edit each file separately - at least, this is how I think it works.

Comment: `shared.config` would NOT be cloned if you 'Add as Link'; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.80).aspx
Are you familiar with this functionality?

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not too familiar with Visual Studio.